# VM is still incurring compute charges, even though it is "stopped"?

Tags: azure, azureportal

I have a VM running Windows on Azure... I do not currently need it running, so I used the Portal and "stopped" it a few months ago.

However, I am still incurring compute charges. And when I visit the Portal, it says the VM is still incurring charges and that I need to "... use the Portal to stop it ...".

But at the same time, the Portal is showing that the VM is already "stopped". I have included a screenshot. Why does it incur compute charges when it is supposedly already "stopped"?

[image: "Stopped" but "not Stopped"?]

Answer (score 1):

This is an Azure "feature". You have to deallocate the VM for it to stop costing you money. The screenshot even says that. To address your second question, if its not incurring charges it would be in `deallocated` state.

If you are using automation, you need to issue the deallocate rest call

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resouceGroups/yyy/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmName/deallocate?api-version=xxx
```